# SourceTree: did you forget to merge?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I have the following:

[image]

I get the following messages when trying to commit:

[image]

I guess the reason why i got the "default" track is that i reverted to an earlier backup. At least that is what i think.

Could someone please give me some advise how to proceed so i can push the current commit i have and operate normally? I have never had any problems like this before and cannot really find a good explanation to how to fix the situation.

**Problem solved:** I finally found the force tab in the bottom on the screen (first picture) and did a force merge from there and that fixed the problem.

Comment: "I guess the reason why i got the "default" track is that i reverted to an earlier backup." I know git better than bitbucket, but that's what it sounds like yes. The equivalent git error would be "non-fast-forward updates were rejected": what it means is that the code you're pushing does not build upon the latest version it has remotely, which will be the case if you're building upon a reverted tree. If you're sure you're not losing anything then the answer is a 'force' push, as in the help text. Or if you did want to start from the remote work, try 'pull'ling it back first.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is were i was able to push the force merge:

[image]